# How to redirect the user back to intended route after social login?

Tags: laravel, authentication

This is my code in LoginController:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    $user = User::where('email', $socialUser->getEmail())->first();

    if (!$user) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
            'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
            'password' => Hash::make('12345678'),
            'social_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    Auth::login($user, true);

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

When performing normal login, it redirects to intended. But, in case of social login, it doesn't. What could be the cause?

Comment: are you using the built-in auth middleware?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the built-in auth middleware and the default web guard for users.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You have to store the path you want to redirect in a session and then redirect the the path intended. I am also using the `Socialite`. Here is how I solved it.

```
public function redirect($provider)
{
    session()->put('intended_url', url()->previous());

    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function callback(Request $request, $provider){

    $intendedUrl = session('intended_url');

    if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied')) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $userSocial =   Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    $users       =   User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();
    if($users){
        Auth::login($users);
        return redirect()->intended($intendedUrl);
    }else{

        $user = User::create([
            'name'          => $userSocial->getName(),
            'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
            'provider_id'   => $userSocial->getId(),
            'provider'      => $provider,
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->intended($intendedUrl);
    }
}
```

Before the redirect I store the previous route and then I use it. So no matter from which URL the user signs in, it will be redirected to the same page.

Comment: I tried this way too. It didn't work for me. I did it again seeing your code. Still, it keeps redirecting to user dashboard.

Comment: This is pretty strange. What is the output of `dd(url()->previous())` ?

Comment: It's this : `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login"`
That's not the right URL.
How do you get the previous URL? 
`url()->previous()` is not working.

Comment: just add return redirect()->intended(); to the callback function on login controlller. thats all. there is no need to put the url to session because its still there ... Session::get('url.intended') is called.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `url()->previous()` in my case I actually needed the current url. So I used  `session()->put('intended_url', url()->full());` in the controller I hit and after lgoin redirect to this url as in the example.
Also you need to use `Session::forget('intended_url');` after assigning it to variable.